# Patterns and file processing

Tags: awk

Let's say I have to perform these actions from an input file:

- extract nth field from a line starting with a given pattern (*in the exemple: 2nd field of the line starting with pattern 'name'*)
- print the field content at the beginning of every following line, while the line does **not** start with the selected pattern
- when a new line matching the pattern is found, repeat step 1 and 2

I'm currently doing this using Python, but it would be better using something light and fast from command line (like awk, for exemple).

Sample input

```
name    NAME_A
inf     field_A1
name    NAME_B 
inf field_B1
inf field_B2
```

Expected output:

```
name    NAME_A
NAME_A  inf field_A1
name    NAME_B 
NAME_B  inf field_B1
NAME_B  inf field_B2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a way to do it. Note the format may vary depending on the field separators you indicate - those you can define with `FS` and `OFS`:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '/^name/ {a=$(n); print; next} {print a, $0}' file
name    NAME_A
NAME_A inf  field_A1
name    NAME_B 
NAME_B inf  field_B1
NAME_B inf  field_B2
```

#### Explanation

- `-v n=2` defines the field number to copy when the pattern is found.
- `/^name/ {a=$(n); print; next}` if the line starts with the given pattern, store the given field and print the line.
- `{print a, $0}` otherwise, print the current line with the stored value first.

You can generalize the pattern part into something like:

```
awk -v n=2 -v pat="name" '$1==pat {a=$(n); print; next} {print a, $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^name  */{h;s///;x;n;};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2        \1/' <<\DATA
name    NAME_A
inf     field_A1
name    NAME_B 
inf field_B1
inf field_B2
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
name    NAME_A
NAME_A  inf     field_A1
name    NAME_B 
NAME_B  inf field_B1
NAME_B  inf field_B2
```

`sed` `h`olds every *name* line and, then removes from same whatever pattern matched it, then it swaps hold space and pattern space before printing,

On every other line, it `G`ets holdspace appended to pattern space with an intervening newline. Then it just swaps the two sides of that newline and replaces it with a tab.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
awk '{print $0 ~ pat ? $0 : p OFS $0   }$0 ~ pat{ p = $NF }' pat='name' file
```